# by protecting their inventions from competition by generics

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand "by generics" as "in the way of medical drugs." Am I on the right track?

> Drugmakers and others who oppose the measure say that waivers sabotage companies’ enormous investments in drug and vaccine development, which are compensated by their ability to set the price on products that they exclusively own. Normally, patents reward pharmaceutical companies **by protecting their inventions from competition by generics** for a limited time — US patents on drugs typically last for 20 years.

> Source: Nature
> [In shock move, US backs waiving patents on COVID vaccines](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01224-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. it is referring to generic drugs (as opposed to name-brand). This may be a US-centric distinction, I don't know, but it is definitely well attested here.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder whether "competition by generics" can be written as "medical drug competition" without altering the original meaning.  The former might be far more accurate than the latter. I don't know.

Comment: FWIW, "generics" is definitely used in the UK - especially since prescriptions are subsidised by the NHS, so doctors are encouraged to prescribe generics rather than brand name drugs.

Comment: @NewPlanet "generics" has a very specific meaning; *generic drugs* are copies of the *same* drug manufactured by other companies after the patent for the first manufacturer ends.  "medical drug competition" could mean competition from *different* drugs even during that patent period.  So the two do not mean the same thing.